# Change the font of article titles in bibliography

Tags: fonts, biblatex

for a school exercise, we need to make changes to the bibliography formatting. The first subtask is to **change the font to Arial** (don't judge my prof, he's a nice guy actually) **for titles of entries of the type `@article`. We have to use `authoryear` as the style and `\DeclareFieldFormat` as the ... command/method**. Easy, right? Hells, I've been looking for five hours on this website and in the following documents, but couldn't figure it out. I need to get some fresh air now.

`authoryear.bbx` `standard.bbx` `biblatex_.def` and the biblatex documentation (English and German versions, the English version has the author chapter, which is missing in the German version) and others.

what it should look like:

[image: supposedly the correct output]

ok, let me tell you, this is not the correct output (but the task is clear about it the Arial part), as the titles of the publications ("Proposing a new..." and "First-Year Wilkinson...") should be written in Arial. Just imagine they are written in Arial, please. The green year and comic sans pages are part of other subtasks.

[image: this is my output with the following code]

The important part here is:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}
{\fontfamily{Arial}}
```

This is my code right now:

```
% -------------
% Header
% -------------
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gentium}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GentiumPlus}

\usepackage{xcolor} % gonna need this later

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references_0303.bib}

% ------------------------------------
% Task Descriptions
% ------------------------------------

% 1. use the authoryear style
% 2. use \DeclareFieldFormat to produce the following adaptations:
% (a) Titles of journal articles are to be written in the Arial font
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}
{\fontfamily{Arial}} % I obviouly have no idea what I'm doing. See output.
% ...
% ... some other task descriptions ...
% ...

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

% Having the bibliography split up like this is part of a later task for which I stumbled upon the solution while doing another exercise, so it's here already, it doesn't influence the task at hand.

\printbibliography[type=book,title=Books]

\printbibliography[type=article,title=Articles]

\printbibliography[nottype=article,nottype=book,title=Other]

\end{document}
```

this is the content of the bibfile:

```
@phdthesis{bruno2003,
    address = {Ann Arbor},
    author = {Bruno, Ana Carla},
    school = {University of Arizona},
    title = {Waimiri Atroari Grammar},
    subtitle = {Some Phonological, Morphological, and Syntactic Aspects},
    year = {2003},
}

@book{olza1994,
    address = {Caracas},
    author = {Olza, Jesús and de Armellada, Cesáreo},
    publisher = {Universidad Católica Andrés Bello},
    title = {Gramática de la lengua Pemón (morfosintaxis)},
    year = {1994},
}

@article{gildea2004,
    author = {Gildea, Spike},
    journal = {Amerindia},
    pages = {7--32},
    title = {Proposing a new branch for the Cariban language family},
    volume = {28},
    year = {2004},
}

@incollection{koehn1986,
    title = {Apalai},
    author = {Koehn, Edward and Koehn, Sally},
    booktitle = {Handbook of Amazonian Languages},
    editor = {Derbyshire, Desmond C. and Pullum, Geoffrey K.},
    volume = {1},
    pages = {33--127},
    year = {1986},
    publisher = {Mouton de Gruyter},
    address = {Berlin/New York},
}

@book{derbyshire1979,
    address = {Amsterdam},
    author = {Derbyshire, Desmond C.},
    publisher = {North-Holland},
    series = {Lingua Descriptive Studies},
    title = {Hixkaryana},
    number = {1},
    year = {1979},
}

@online{glottolog,
    author = {Hammarström, Harald and Forkel, Robert and Haspelmath, Martin and Bank, Sebastian},
    year = {2016},
    title = {Glottolog 2.7},
    location = {Jena},
    school = {Max Planck Institute for the Science of Human History},
    url = {http://glottolog.org},
    urldate = {2016-06-22},
}

@inproceedings{salam,
    author = {Salam, Abdus},
    editor = {Svartholm, Nils},
    title = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
    date = {1968},
    booktitle = {Elementary particle theory},
    booksubtitle = {Relativistic groups and analyticity},
    booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the Eighth Nobel Symposium},
    eventdate = {1968-05-19/1968-05-25}, % output: 19.-25. Mai 1968
    venue = {Aspenäsgarden, Lerum},
    publisher = {Almquist \& Wiksell},
    location = {Stockholm},
    pages = {367--377},
}

@collection{dixon2003word,
    title = {Word},
    subtitle = {A cross-linguistic typology},
    editor = {Dixon, Robert and Aikhenvald, Alexandra},
    year = {2003},
    address = {Cambridge},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
}

@techreport{rfc1654,
    author = {Yakov Rekhter and Tony Li},
    title = {A Border Gateway Protocol 4 (BGP-4)},
    howpublished = {Internet Requests for Comments},
    type = {RFC},
    number = {1654},
    pages = {1-56},
    year = {1995},
    month = {07},
    issn = {2070-1721},
    publisher = {RFC Editor},
    institution = {RFC Editor},
    url = {http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1654.txt},
}

@misc{isotest,
    author = {{DIN ISO 8037-1:2003-05}},
    title = {Optik und optische Instrumente - Mikroskope; Objektträger - Teil 1},
    subtitle = {Maße, optische Eigenschaften und Kennzeichnung},
    year = {1986},
}

@article{spergel2003,
    author = {D. N. Spergel and L. Verde and H. V. Peiris and E. Komatsu and M. R. Nolta and C. L. Bennett and M. Halpern and G. Hinshaw and N. Jarosik and A. Kogut and M. Limon and S. S. Meyer and L. Page and G. S. Tucker and J. L. Weiland and E. Wollack and E. L. Wright},
    title = {First-Year Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe (WMAP) Observations},
    subtitle = {Determination of Cosmological Parameters},
    journal = {The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series},
    volume = {148},
    number = {1},
    pages = {175--194},
    year = {2003},
}
```

Comment: `\fontspec{Arial}` maybe?

Comment: `\setsansfont{Arial}` and `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\sffamily}`.

Comment: actually, don't loose your head over it. Apparently, I have a `{#1}` missing somewhere. That's why it doesn't print. But then, I think `\fontspec` should do the trick, as I am not looking for a fontfamily, but for a specific font. Sorry for the long, buggy question.

Comment: So, just for informative purposes, the line I was looking for had indeed `fontspec`in it: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\fontspec{Arial}{#1}}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not existing anymore, see the answer by the op

Comment: @samcarter  -- that's not a valid close reason.  There is still archival value.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Closing is not deleting.

Comment: @T.Verron  Closed questions are candidates for deletion.  Valid close reasons are that the question needs work or that it is somehow a poor fit for the site.  The fact that it is answered by the asker is not a close reason.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I just saw the answer to the question (does the reopen queue even show the answer?), I see your point now. Just for the record, I never meant to imply that self-answering was a reason for deletion, but rather that this question looked like a typical case of "solved once the syntax error is spotted", which usually bear very little archival value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's the right way to do this, but this question doesn't need an answer any more, as I was asking for something, but the problem was something else. Mods can comment on the correct procedure in such a case.

I just wanted to take this question off the list of unanswered questions and hint to the fact that we found a solution in the comments to the question. I could delete the question, but then again, somebody might be looking for the easiest way to alter the font in a specific part of the bibliography and be persistent throughout the whole file.

The correct to be inserted is as follows:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\fontspec{Arial}{#1}}
```

where `{#1}` is a placeholder for the text of the respective field (in this case the title of the article). This was missing in the question, so the code couldn't parse correctly. Additionally, as pointed out in one of the comments by @johannes-b, `\fontspec` must be used instead of `\fontfamily` to choose the required font.

PS: Should I check this as community wiki? I don't really understand the purpose of this, yet.
Oh and please, definitely don't upvote any of this, as I will see myself bound to delete the whole thing (provided I have the privilege to do so).

Comment: Then put the comment in your answer!!  Attribute it if you must.  Comments may someday be deleted, answers will not.

Comment: Why don't you just include your the correct line `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\fontspec{Arial}{#1}}` in your answer and accept it? It might help other people with the same problem. And since you basically found the answer yourself, that is a very valid option.

Comment: No you shouldn't check it as community wiki, and you definitely mustn't delete anything. You can see the upvotes as steps towards more responsibilities on the site if it makes you feel better.

Comment: @T.Verron ok, will do. thanks for the feedback.