# Change font of the word URL before the actual url in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, url

I´m working on my bibliography and wanted to change the font style of the URL. This I was able to do with `\usepackage{url}` and `\urlstyle{same}`. After compiling the font changed but not of the word 'URL:'. This you can see below.
[image]

I tried to redefine the style like mentioned in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337971/change-the-font-of-article-titles-in-bibliography) question. But this didn´t work. I hope you have any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
language = ngerman]{biblatex}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Dantam.2018,
    author = {Dantam, Neil},
    title = {Quaternion Computation},
    url = {http://www.neil.dantam.name/note/dantam-quaternion.pdf},
    urldate = {2018-01-05},
    abstract = {},
    organization = {{Institute for Robotics and Intelligent Machines, Georgia Institute of Technology}},
    shorthand = {DANT18}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with 'URL'? At the moment it is just the output you get from `\textsc{url}`. The string is set with `\mkbibacro`, the current definition is `\newcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{\ifcsundef{\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/sc}{#1}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}`

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn´t aware that this was in lower case. But your other comment works also fine for me. It does exactly what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change the URL font, you could use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{URL\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

to obtain it in standard capital letters, instead of small caps.

But, a more general, and appropriate approach, would be to redefine the macro that sets "URL" in small caps, for it affects other acronyms as well (such as 
"DOI", "ISBN", "ISSN" and so on). So, for consistency, a general redefinition of `\mkbibacro` would be better (as well noted in the comments by moewe):

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{#1}
```

The result of either (though the second one is to be preferred) would be:

[image]

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
language = ngerman]{biblatex}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Dantam.2018,
    author = {Dantam, Neil},
    title = {Quaternion Computation},
    url = {http://www.neil.dantam.name/note/dantam-quaternion.pdf},
    urldate = {2018-01-05},
    abstract = {},
    organization = {{Institute for Robotics and Intelligent Machines, Georgia Institute of Technology}},
    shorthand = {DANT18}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `biblatex` defines a dedicated macro for acronyms, `\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{#1}` might me more appropriate.

Comment: @moewe, I thought only of the job at hand. But you are correct, of course. (As usual!)